# How to use rails link_to with a bootstrap badge

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, button

I currently have a navbar that is made of links as shown below.

**NAVBAR:**

```
<li>
  <%= link_to "Messages (#{@user.messages.count})", "#messages", "data-toggle" => :tab %>
</li>
<li>
  <%= link_to "Notes (#{@user.notes.count})", "#notes", "data-toggle" => :tab %></li>
</li>
```

What I would really like to do is make these links buttons that have an embedded badge displaying the count similar to below. I just cannot figure out how to do that with rails.

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">
  Messages <span class="badge">4</span>
</button>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use the `link_to` [block method](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to):

```
<%= link_to '#messages', class: 'btn btn-primary', data: {toggle: :tab} do %>
    Messages <%= content_tag :span, @user.messages.count, class: 'badge' %>
<% end %>
```

Alternatively, if you're set on using a single line, you could use a helper like this:

```
def text_with_badge(text, badge_value=nil)
    badge = content_tag :span, badge_value, class: 'badge'
    text = raw "#{text} #{badge}" if badge_value
    return text
end
```

and then call :

```
<%= link_to text_with_badge('Messages', @user.messages.count), '#messages', class: 'btn btn-primary', data: {toggle: :tab} %>
```

or go the extra mile of creating your own `link_to_with_badge` helper.